# HTML/CSS Center Horizontally on Unordered List not working

Tags: html, css

In my HTML I have an unordered list of links. In my CSS I am trying to center the list of links horizontally on the webpage. Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px, auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: black;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-inline: 0.5rem;
}

li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, li a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS Display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav> 
        
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I thought setting the unordered list to an inline-block would allow me to apply margins onto the unordered list element. If so, my margins were set to margin: 0px, auto; which should have centered the unordered list horizontally, but for some reason none of the CSS is being applied. I am very much focused on WHY this does not work rather than an alternative solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you need to do:

1 . Give `display: flex` to your `nav`

```
nav{
 display: flex
}
```

2 . margin is not correctly provided for `ul`, it should be without a comma

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

---

***Working code below:***

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

body {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-inline: 0.5rem;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
li a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CSS Display</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Why does adding flex to nav work for this solution?

Comment: The parent container for the margin auto must be defined with a width to make the child center; since we don't want to limit ourself with a defined manual width; `flex` and `grid` take up the whole width available, in short both flex and grid can work here

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
margin: 0px, auto;
```

To this:

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

To fix the issue, you can change the comma to a space. This should center your unordered list horizontally on the webpage.

Comment: This solution did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Kamil is correct. There is an error in your syntax. Remove the comma from your margin declaration.

To center your list you should remove `display:inline-block;` from your ul and add a width less than 100%. This will allow your list to be centered on the page.

Inline-block elements do not have an inherent width. Therefore, `margin:auto;` will not work.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

ul {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: black;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-inline: 0.5rem;
}

li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, li a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS Display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav> 
        
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```